# Can't find jar binaries

Tags: arch-linux, java, openjdk

I installed jdk8 and jdk14 on Arch Linux with

```
sudo pacman -S jre8-openjdk jre-openjdk
```

but I can't find the jar binaries file. If I run

```
jar
```

it tells me command not found.

I searched in both openjdk folder but I cant find it. Even with

```
sudo find / -name jar
```

it finds nothing.

Any ideas why?

I also tried

```
sudo archlinux-java fix
```

Comment: why do you believe that the jar binary is named `jar`? ... where did you get that information?

Comment: @jsotola: `man jar` on my system shows `jar - Manipulates Java Archive (JAR) files.`. It's a part of jdk package.

Comment: @jsotola I just guessed it, normally you can run `jar -cf` so the bin should be called jar or at least a link to it.

Comment: On Linux Mint, the `jar` binary is in the **openjdk-11-jdk-headless** package (also in **openjdk-8-jdk-headless**). Is there something similar on Arch?

Comment: @ajgringo619 I also have jre8-openjdk-headless and jre-openjdk-headless both installed.

Comment: Does this exist: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar`. If not, search for `bin/jar` under `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have installed the `jre` packages which are just the runtime packages.

To get the `jar` binaries, you need to install the `jdk` packages which are the development packages:

```
jdk-openjdk

jdk8-openjdk
```

The binaries will located in the following respective directories:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk/bin

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin
```

You need to prepend the directory for the version that you want to use to your `PATH` and the `lib` directory to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (using 14 as an example):

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk/bin:$PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Add those lines to your shell init files, `~/.bashrc` if using BASH, so that they will be added to your environment at login.

You'll then see the binary when you run:

```
which jar
```

Comment: Oh. i thought i had the jdk installed. The package name fooled me. And i could also compile with javac.